# TileMill shows black lines around raster layers

Tags: mapnik, tilemill, mapbox

I've taken a large number of raster images and added them to TileMill. Everything has worked great. The problem that I am seeing is that TileMill adds a small black line around each layer. I know that the layers overlap so there shouldn't be any gaps in between the layers. Is there an easy way to get rid of the black lines? These lines do not show when viewing the raster layers in QGIS.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was answered here: http://support.mapbox.com/discussions/tilemill/1773-tilemill-shows-black-lines-around-raster-layers-2. Solution: use VRT files to reference multiple rasters.